# Downgrade Node on MacBook

Tags: javascript, npm

I installed the latest version of Node on their website, but I had issues with png and segmentation errors and such, looked it up and saw that it is a common issue on version 16. So I decided to downgrade to the stable version (14), which I have been unable to do. I've tried

```
npm install -g node@14.17.1
```

After running this and doing node -v, it still shows the latest version (16). How can I uninstall version 16 and only be on the stable version (14)?

Comment: I'd recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: you might have to kill the process and restart to see the version reflected - also using NVM for this is usually the way to go

Comment: I restarted my Mac and it still says version 16. Isn't NVM for if you want multiple node versions? I only want one, the stable one.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) Here, you can get brief details on [how to use nvm](https://blog.jamesauble.com/install-nvm-on-mac-with-brew-adb921fb92cc?gi=55b20ebe9558). nvm is a version manager for node.js, designed to be installed **per-user**, and invoked **per-shell**. nvm works on any POSIX-compliant shell (sh, dash, ksh, zsh, bash), in particular on these platforms: Unix, macOS, and windows WSL.

The best thing is, you can run multiple versions of node at the same time on a different shell, It's like version manager on steroids. Please check this also [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package.

Answer (score 1):

Find out where is the current node and delete

```
where node
```

Install nvm

[For macOS](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases)

Show all the versions

```
nvm ls available
```

Install what you want

```
nvm install 14.17.1
nvm use 14.17.1
```

Check node version

```
node -v
```